# How to resolve: Django make migrate not running in AWS ECS from Dockerfile

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, database-migration

I have a Django project that runs in a Docker container. Locally when I have updated the project to include changes to the model, I have run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` within the docker container. In particular, I would enter the container from the terminal and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to execute the changes. This worked locally. However, now that I have pushed my code to production (AWS ECS) for some reason `manage.py` is not running to update the existing database. There is no evidence that `manage.py` is running in the logs, even though it is in my `entrypoint.sh` script. Are there any additional configs that I need to set up either in the Dajngo project or in AWS ECS to be able to run migrations in the AWS ECS environment? The project is otherwise running fine, so the docker container is up, just `python manage.py migrate` is never run.

I have included the `Dockerfile` below for reference:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm

ENV uid=1000
ENV gid=1000

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV USER=app_user UID=$uid GID=$gid

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata libpcre3 libpython3-dev libpcre3-dev python3-pip build-essential libpq-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /app

COPY Makefile pyproject.toml poetry.lock /tmp/

RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

WORKDIR /tmp


RUN make requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && rm -rf requirements.txt \
    && groupadd -f --gid "${GID}" "${USER}" \
    && useradd ${USER} --uid ${UID} --gid ${GID} \
    && install -d -m 0755 -o ${USER} -g ${USER} /app/static

RUN apt-get purge -y libpython3-dev python3-pip build-essential libpq-dev libpcre3-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN rm -rf /tmp/*

COPY book_store /app

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
COPY post-deployment.sh /app/post-deployment.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

I have included the `entrypoint.sh` below for reference:

```
./manage.py wait_for_database
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput || true
./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If that is your entrypoint script, and yet you don't see those commands running in the ECS logs, what exactly do you see in the logs? Please note that you mention the `makemigrations` command several times in your question, but you don't have that command in your `Dockerfile` or your `entrypoint.sh` script. You have the `migrate` command only. You should at least see the `migrate` command in the logs, but it may not have any migrations to run since you don't have the `makemigrations` command in there.

Comment: Locally, I have run `makemigrations` so there are migrations that have been pushed as part of the change. My understanding is as long as there is a migrations folder, `migrate` should create those migrations. That's why in my `entrypoint.sh` I only have `migrate`

Comment: Yes as long as the migration files are in the docker image it should pick them up. Your question simply wasn't clear about that, since you said you have run "python manage.py makemigrations" **within the docker container**. If you did that, and didn't create a new docker image from that container, then the migrations would **NOT** be in the image you pushed to AWS.

Comment: How would I be able to create a new docker image from that container? Aside from that, would a solution be to add `makemigrations` in the `entrypoint.sh` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the `makemigrations` command from a docker container locally. Any changes you make in a docker container do not get saved to the image the container was created from. A Docker image is like a snapshot of a point in time. Anything you do with container(s) you create from that image do not affect the image itself. To create a new docker image from a running container, to include updates you have made in that container, you would use the [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) command. There is an issue here however, that you would be starting from an empty set of migrations every time you create an image, so the migrations that had already been applied would be missing from the `/migrations` folder the next time you create an image, which is going to result in errors.

I do not recommend running `makemigrations` in the `entrypoint.sh`, because you will run into the same issue with the previous migration files being missing, and the new migrations not matching exactly what has been applied already, causing errors on subsequent `makemigrations` runs.

The typical way to manage Django migration files is to create them once, and save them as part of your source code in your source repository (Git). You would do this *before* creating the container image from the `Dockerfile`, so that the migrations would automatically be part of the Python code that gets included in the created image. By storing the migration files in your Git repository, when you later run `makemigrations` again, it will have the previous migrations available in the `/migrations` folder, and will build on those, instead of creating an entirely new set of migrations each time. This is the method I recommend.

Comment: I'm doing this from an existing project that runs in an existing docker container. I was not able to run `makemigrations` from outside of the docker container initially when I made the model changes. The only way I was able to run `makemigrations` successfully was from within the container. That being said, all migrations are stored locally in the source repository (Git). I'm not sure how I would do run `makemigrations` without entering the container. I tried doing it outside the container and the changes didn't get applied. I will try the docker commit command.

Comment: If you have existing migrations stored in the source repository, but you are running `makemigrations` in a docker container, you are not storing *new* migrations in the source repository. You are creating them in the docker container and then basically throwing them away. The `docker commit` command is not going to work well for you here, because you still won't be persisting the migrations in source control, so the next time you need to make migrations you will run into errors.

Comment: When you run the local container to make migrations, you need to either copy those new migrations out of the container, and into your source control, or have a path mapped from the container to your local `/migrations` folder. Only after you have the new migrations in source control should you then create a new docker image from your updated source, and push that to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue. You may need to ensure that the user running the django application within the docker container has the permission to run the migrations commands..

Maybe try to be explicit by setting the owner of the app directory to the specified user. Try adding the following below your mkdir command in your dockerfile or anywhere suitable.

```
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Set ownership for the /app directory
RUN groupadd -f --gid "${GID}" "${USER}" \
&& useradd ${USER} --uid ${UID} --gid ${GID} \
&& chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /app
```